# json migration to nodes

Tags: migrations, 8

I have a json file with 572 items. I have created the migration script and it runs ok, except that the end results says

> processed 572 items (1 created, 571 updated)

It looks like instead of creating one node for each item, only one node is created and then overwritten, so that only the last item shows.

I am guessing that I have problems with the `item_selector: nlm` from my json file with starts with

```
{
  "nlm": [
    {RECORD # : .....},
    {RECORD # : .....},
    ...
  ]
}
```

But changing the `item_selector` to anything else gives an error and the script doesn't run.

Any idea of how to get the script to create 572 nodes will be helpful.

Thanks

Edit:
my migration script looks like this:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: importjson3e
class: null
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags: null
migration_group: null
label: 'New JSON migration'
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: json
  include_raw_data: true
  urls: 'http://example.com/json/nlm_0119.json'
  track_changes: true
  item_selector: 'nlm'
  fields:
    -
      name: year_added
      label: YearAdded
      selector: YearAdded
    -
      name: month_added
      label: MonthAdded
      selector: MonthAdded
    -
      name: record_number
      label: 'RECORD # '
      selector: 'RECORD # '
    -
      name: Title
      label: 'TITLE '
      selector: 'TITLE '

  ids:
    record_number:
      type: text
process:
   type:
     plugin: default_value
     default_value: new_books
  title: Title
  field_year_added: year_added
  field_month_added: month_added
  field_record_number: record_number
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
migration_dependencies: null
```

Comment: That message sounds more to me like 1 was created, and 571 already existed and were updated. Are you sure that there is only one node?

Comment: In order to receive any advice what might be worth changing, you should consider to also adding your migration configuration to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment your selectors, and your `item_selector` should be:

`nlm/` and not just `nlm`.

I had this same issue when I was setting up a JSON migration and that was the first thing I ran into.

Comment: Wow! Can't believe it was that simple. Changing the item_selector to nlm/ worked. Thanks

Comment: Yep, the slash is important. Wish it was a bit more documented.